# How to enable javascript enhancement of phpdocs?

Tags: php, phpdoc

The questions has it all. I'm currently using -o HTML:frames:earthli but that does not have the javascript. I can't seem to find documentation on how to enable it.

Example: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/DOM/earthli/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the earthli theme with the javascript menus, then use

**-o HTML:frames:DOM/earthli**

Just using -o HTML:frames:earthli doesn't do it.